# MongoDB Get Field to Update a Value from Request Query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have user object structured like this:

```
{
  "id": "",
  "username": "",
  "name": "",
  "bio": "",
  "email": "",
  "profileImg": "",
  "phoneNumber": 0,
  "messagingPoints": 0,
  "funds": 0,
  "inventoryId": "",
  "lastLogin": "2022-02-23T03:27:13.535Z",
  "isPrivate": false,
  "messagesReceived": []
}
```

I want to be able to reach a patch endpoint to update any of these fields. For example, /api/user?id=userId&name=John, should be able to grab the field "name" and set it to John. /api/user/id=?id=userId&email=abc@gmail.com should grab the email field and set it to abc@gmail.com

I am struggling to find docs for MongoDB to accomplish this, so I'm wondering if it is not possible? Do I need a specific endpoint for each of these update operations (ex: /api/user/name?id=userId&value=John instead of /api/user?id=userId&name=John)?

If it is possible, how could I accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: Whose email or name is the API supposed to updated? You must be passing user ID somehow? Also if you are making a patch request, you can pass the data in the request body or is there a reason to use query params ?

Comment: My mistake, the correct endpoint example is /api/user?id=userID&name=John. And no, there is no specific reason to use query params, if request body is the usual way that information is sent that I can use that instead

Comment: I've posted an answer, do ensure that if ID field is string then you pass in string. Else the documents won't match if it's string in document and you are passing number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass user ID in update filter. Also you can pass data in request body of the PUT request instead of query parameters.

```
app.put('/api/user', async (req, res) => {
  const { id, ...data } = req.body; 
  // Filter out any invalid fields

  // Update documents where id field is equal to value of id in request body
  await collection.updateOne(
    { id },
    { $set: data }
  );

  return res.json({ data: "User updated" })
})
```